# How to make ActiveRecord execute SQL to load association when the parent model object is not persisted yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, persistence, associations

I am doing things in a non-standard way. I am assigning IDS on object creation.

So, during before_save callbacks, which access a parent model's child association collections, I have this issue, where ActiveRecord won't actually execute the SQL to lookup the child association.

I can get the associated objects by doing a find on their class, as shown below, but is there any way to force the collection association methods to actually run the query and fetch the children when the parent itself has not been saved yet?

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

3.times do
  Task.create(:project_id => 1)
end

Tasks.where(:project_id => 1).count
# 3

tasks = Tasks.where(:project_id => 1)
# SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE project_id = 1;

p = Project.new(:id => 1)
p.tasks # nil
# no SQL query executed
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no SQL executed because you haven't saved your Project record yet. Try changing Project.new(:id => 1) to Project.create!(:id => 1) and then query your tasks.

In other words, your project doesn't exist, so why would it look for tasks underneath it?

Comment: That's the whole point of my question. My project doesn't exist yet in the database. So, how do I force ActiveRecord to execute the query for the child associations, based on the ID attribute that I have set in the new, non-persisted Project?

Comment: I don't think it will. While the project instance exists in the memory, it doesn't in the db. Until you persist the object, it won't create the relation.

Comment: So... there should be some way, deep inside of active record. We know (from my example above) that the data I want from `p.tasks` exists, and from my testing I know that for a persisted object, the SQL is executed, but for a non-persisted object, the SQL is not even attempted. If we can find out what is causing ActiveRecord to take the non-sql branch then I should be able to find the answer to my question.

Comment: So, to summarize, you want a way for AR to recognize that although the object upon which you're executing an action isn't persisted, it should nevertheless use its ID which has been set manually and therefore NOT in the database to query for objects in the database. You also see nothing wrong with this and feel that AR should be able to pull it off within normal use cases. Good luck and I mean that sincerely

Comment: I think I made it pretty clear in my question I am aware that I am not doing things the standard way, and I am in search of a way to *force* ActiveRecord to work how I want it to. I'm sure you can think of a practical reason for assigning IDS manually at creation? I am using this technique to keep two separate systems in sync with one another. The ID that they share across two databases is a unique key across the global system. I've obviously simplified my question to generalize it. Thank you for your input though.